# How to Open Fullscreen video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I make video's interactive with several buttons link to several elements, but this elements are the best show in Fullscreen, so I'm searching for a solution to integrate a code (if possible) so that when I click on the video on my site, the video will be automatically Fullscreen. Is this possible?

```
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; "><iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no" style="width: 1px; min-width: 100%; *width: 100%;" height="100%" src="https://playfilmstorage.blob.core.windows.net/media/published/398548bd-4bc9-42cf-ab5e-bd6a922afbf0/index.html?autoplay=false"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: fullscreen can not be done automatically without a user event triggering it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
There is a solution with javascript. It's working for Mozilla and Webkit browsers.

You can use `element.mozRequestFullScreen();` and `element.webkitRequestFullScreen();`

Example :

```js
function goFullscreen(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   }
}
```

```html
<img class="video_player" src="image.jpg" id="player"></img>
<button onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">Fullscreen</button>
```

To allow fullscreen mode for an `<iframe>` elements, you need to set your iframe on `allowFullScreen`:

```html
<iframe src="iframe.html" width="100" height="100" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```